# How to embed ExoPlayer in android library?

Tags: android, android-library, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to embed ExoPlayer to android library, how can I do it, is any ideas?

Comment: How would using ExoPlayer in a library be different from using it in a regular android application project?

Comment: I need to include ExoPlayer to my aar file with all sources code, layouts and ect. My library will be used by other developers to build their own apps, and I want that they add only one dependency - my library, not all dependencies that used by me to create my library.

Comment: vchernychov: If you include ExoPlayer in your library's gradle file, users wont have to add the dependency again to their own project, they just need to add yours.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @user1354603 I simply add exoplayer in this way:

`compile libraries.exoCore
compile libraries.exoDash
compile libraries.exoHls
compile libraries.exoSmoothstreaming`

and in doc of library said that it depended on exoplayer

Answer (score 0):

You can just include it in your `build.gradle` file of your library and you'll have access to it. You can follow the guide [here](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#getting-started).

Make sure jcenter is one of your listed repositories

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Then add the compile statement into your dependencies.

`compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.2'`

Then follow the rest of the guide I posted to get an ExoPlayer instance up and running.

Answer (score 0):

:) I added it in my App -> build.gradle inside of dependecies section

```
dependencies {


        compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.4.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.1'
}
```